# Excel Convert Alphanumeric Values to Number

Tags: excel, currency

I have a bunch of dollar figures formatted like "$43.7 B" and "$667 M" in several columns in Excel. How do I convert these to "$43,700,000,000" and "$667,000,000" respectively?

This seems likes it should be easy but I am stumped.

Comment: [Formula for smart, scale-aware number-formatting in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/77974/formula-for-smart-scale-aware-number-formatting-in-google-sheets-e-g-1-024-%E2%86%92/78069#78069)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))*POWER(10,6+(RIGHT(A1)="B")*3)
'if you receive a #VALUE error then,
=MID(A1, 2, FIND(" ",A1)-1)*POWER(10,6+(RIGHT(A1)="B")*3)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't believe it is from formatting. After rereading the question I believe it is the reverse of formatting so I reopened it.

Comment: ... and yet mine does.